# List files not containing certain string in cmd

Tags: cmd

With the below code, I'm trying to list files from all folders and subdirectory which does not have a string `fontIndex` but it does not list anything nor any error.

```
for %a in ("dir /s *.*") do @findstr "fontIndex" "%a" >nul || echo %a
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation of `for`? type `for /?` into a command prompt window to get the help. So either do `for /R %a in ("*.*") do ...` or do `for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir /S /B /A:-D "*.*"') do ...`. Note that `%a` must be changed to `%%a` when being used within a batch file. By the way, instead of `||` just change the `findstr` command line to this: `findstr /M /V "fontIndex" "%a"` (*no* `>nul`!)...

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
findstr /i /v /m /L /s "FontIndex" *.*
```

/i for case-insensitive
/v not-match
/m filename only
/L literal
/s and subdirectories

Your code does not work because the `dir/s` output is not a list of filenames-only - that would be `dir /s /b /a-d` and you're getting no output because the `>nul` disposes of the output (send it to oblivion).

To find files that contain "Fontindex" but not "Fontindex1" (where `1` may ve any alphameric, use

```
findstr /i /m /R /s "FontIndex[^0-9a-z]" *.*
```

That is, `/R` ("regular expression") specified to be `Fontindex` followed immediately by `^` NOT the [group of characters, where `-` means range]

I didn't test the `/v` version as the valid/invalid combinations were simply too bothersome for me to evaluate.

Comment: Actually I've strings like `fontIndex2`, `fontIndex1` in files and those files should not be listed. I tried changing code, but no luck. Tried this: `findstr /v /m /s "fontIndex" *.*`

Comment: @Experimenter, open up a Command Prompt window then, enter `findstr /?` and read its usage information. You may find that using one or both of the `Word position:` Regular expressions would serve you better. This however, as far as your question is concerned, and based upon your lack of supporting information, is outside of the scope of this answer.

Comment: What is the use of /L flag? can you explain more about it please?

Comment: @PravejKhan : In this instance, it's redundant. By default, `findstr` uses `/r` to invoke a regular-expression match (it's not a complete regex implementation). `/L` forces the strings provided to be used literally.